# Add exception to min/max value in numberfield extjs 3

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

a numberfield like this

```
xtype            : 'numberfield',  
fieldLabel       : 'this is a label',
id               : 'id',
name             : 'id', 
width            : 50,
labelStyle       : 'width:300px',
minValue         : 1,
hideTrigger      : true,
allowNegative    : false,
maxValue         : 7,
decimalPrecision : 1,
allowPureDecimal : true,
editable         : true,   
allowBlank       : false
```

Accept numbers 1, 1.1, 3.5 ... 7

But i need **accept 0 too**. Exists in extjs a property like exception or something that allows entering the 0 and also the minimum and maximum values that are established?

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does minValue: 0 not work?

Comment: yes but i dont need values 0.1  - 0.2 - 0.9  and minvalue 0 accept that numbers

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `minValue` and `maxValue` configs and then set a custom validation function using the [validator](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validator) config.

```
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    fieldLabel: 'this is a label',
    id: 'id',
    name: 'id',
    hideTrigger: true,
    allowNegative: false,
    decimalPrecision: 1,
    allowPureDecimal: true,
    editable: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    validator() {
        value = this.getValue();
        if (value === 0 || (value >= 1 && value <=7)) {
            return true;
        }
        return 'Not valid';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a property to do that, but you could register a **change listener** and check if the **newValue parameter** is between 0 and 1. If so, set numberfield's value to zero.

```
listeners: {
    change: function (component, newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue > 0 && newValue < 1)
            component.setValue(0);
    }
}
```